# How many args does runState in haskell have

Tags: haskell

**I misread the documentation.**

Consider `runState` as defined in [mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:runState).

`s -> (a, s) :: State s a`

Does what look like two arguments for `runState` have something to do with the `s` and `Identity` in `StateT s Identity`?

Comment: Every function in Haskell takes one argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misreading the type signature.

```
runState :: State s a -> s -> (a, s)
```

This type signature indicates directly that runState takes 2 arguements. The first is of type `State s a`, and the second is of type `s`.